# Render rabl rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have root with params:
localhost:3000/points/mypoint.json?access_token=acuotodEhqyFnVQPJ2AK
This root will return list points of all restaurant of users (get user from access_token)
My code:

```
def mypoint
      @locations = Location.select("locations.*")
end
def totalpoint
    @totalpoint = 0
    return 0 if self.user_points.point.count==0
    self.user_points.point.collect { |p| @totalpoint = @totalpoint +p.points}
    return @totalpoint
end
scope :point, where( "points IS NOT ?", nil )
```

Rabl file:

```
collection @locations
attributes :name, :totalpoint
```

Database:

```
--id---user_id---point_type--restaurant_id---points---
  1       1       favourite       1            50
  2       7       ratings         1            123
  3       7       comments        1            50
  4       7       comments        2            50
  5       7       ratings         2            10
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "quoc",
        "totalpoint": 223
    },
    {
        "name": "Restaurant_id2",
        "totalpoint": 60
    }
]
```

But this is result list points of all restaurant do not regarding user. 
Please tell me add condition user_id in totalpoint method.
I want to result below
Result with user_id = 1:

```
[
    {
        "name": "quoc",
        "totalpoint": 50
    },
    {
        "name": "Restaurant_id2",
        "totalpoint": 0
    }
]
```

Result with user_id = 7:

```
[
    {
        "name": "quoc",
        "totalpoint": 173
    },
    {
        "name": "Restaurant_id2",
        "totalpoint": 60
    }
]
```

Please give me your solution.Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

detail your question properly, it took me 15 min to understand!

You can write the method inside model itself. What is the model name?
To get the list of points by user_id

First find all unique user_id and restaurant_id

```
      a=Model.select("DISTINCT(restaurant_id)")
      b=Model.select("DISTINCT(user_id)")
```

Now a=[1,2] and b=[1,7] for this example, now get all the points collected by users in each restaurant.

```
     score=Array.new

     b.each do |k|
       rest=Hash.new
       a.each do |f|
          rest[f]=Model.find(:all,:conditions=>["user_id=? and restaurant_id",k,f],:select=>["points"] )
       end
     score<<rest
      end
```

This will do it.

Comment: is my answer correct? if it is please tick it as correct answer.